# How to trigger NoOp for key combinations in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey, shift

I am trying to put conditions on my Shift keys so that I use the correct shift keys. I should not use `LShift + a` instead I should use `RShift + a`. So `LShift + a` should be a NOOP.

Something like below that can be done using [Karabiner](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/#better-shifting)

```
<item>
    <name>Use the correct shift keys.</name>
    <identifier>private.correct_shift_keys</identifier>

    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::W, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::R, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::T, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::D, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::G, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Z, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>

    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::Y,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::U,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::I,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::O,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::P,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::H,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::J,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::K,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::L,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SEMICOLON, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::N,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::M,         ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::COMMA,     ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::DOT,       ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::QUOTE,     ModifierFlag::SHIFT_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
</item>
```

How can I add similar conditions to LShift and RShift in an AutoHotkey script? How can I mention that a key combination should be NOOP.
Something like,

```
; Correct Shift Key Conditions
LShift & a::NOOP
RShift & l::NOOP
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable the hotkeys with the `return` command.

```
; Disable left shift, left letter keys
LShift & q::return
LShift & w::return
; ...
LShift & w::return

; Disable right shift, right letter keys
RShift & y::return
RShift & u::return
; ...
RShift & m::return
```

Note: Look up the codes for the symbols you want to omit as well.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm
https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm